# permissions and acknowledgments in publish LaTeX-composed material

Tags: multicol, publishing, licensing

I've just completed composing a scholarly book using LaTeX and it has been accepted for publication. Are there legal requirements for 1) acknowledgments or 2) permissions connected with the use of LaTeX in a published book? I don't see anything about the latter in the current versions of the docs for the packages I've used.

---

***Edit***: Frank Mittelbach has pointed me to a paper he has recently published on the history of the LaTeX Project Public License: [*TUGboat* 32(2011)/1:83–94](http://www.latex-project.org/papers/tb100mittbach-lppl-history.pdf). Section 1.2 (p. 84) contains a digression on the `multicol` license and its current status. He describes the `multicol` "moral obligation" license as "perhaps the most curious license ever drawn up."

Comment: 'LaTeX' here is a bit loose. Some packages may require some statements, others do not, and the kernel itself is separate again.

Comment: @Joseph do you have any example of this? Especially stemming from packages included in default installations like TeX Live or MikTeX. I've only seen one such file. Where one was actually asked to send the author a copy of each work one produced with the aid of his macros. I have naturally denied to globally install these macros on our system.

Comment: @daleif Well, most famously there is the 'moral obligation' clause for `multicol`. More broadly, the question does not limit us to packages in TL/MiKTeX.

Comment: the ams doesn't require any statements about the use of (La)TeX, although some authors do choose to acknowledge its use.  i've seen this usually either in the formal acknowledgments (sometimes a section in the preface or as a final "afterword"), or as a statement ``Typeset with LaTeX'' on the copyright page.  but, except for a few specific packages as mentioned by daleif and joseph, it's not a legal requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I know of no package or software in the TeX world with a *legal* or *moral* requirement of acknowledgments like the advertising clause in the old [BSD license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).

AFAIK `multicol` is the only one with a *moral obligation* clause for payment; commercial software and some packages exist(ed).

Comment: Never knew about `multicol`, just serves to show how much attention normal people give to licenses within the products they use

Comment: @dalei: `multicol` asks you for payment, not for acknowledgments.

Comment: Also, it asks for a payment on a moral scale, which means that you decide what the appropriate fee is :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Usually Frank get's a beer whenever I meet him. `:-)`

Comment: @JosephWright so so ... I get a beer each time I meet Martin, good to know, perhaps I should cash in on that :-)